# Matlab: repeat every column sequentially n times

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat

I'm pretty much beginner so it's probably possible to do what I want in a simple way. 
I have a matrix 121x62 but I need to expand it to 121x1488 so every column has to be repeated 24 times. For example, transform this:

```
   2.2668       2.2667       2.2667       2.2666       2.2666       2.2666       
   2.2582       2.2582       2.2582       2.2582       2.2581       2.2581       
    2.283        2.283        2.283       2.2829       2.2829       2.2829       
   2.2881       2.2881       2.2881       2.2881       2.2881        2.288        
    2.268        2.268       2.2679       2.2679       2.2678       2.2678       
   2.2742       2.2742       2.2741       2.2741       2.2741        2.274
```

into this:

```
2.2668     2.2668     2.2668  and so on to 24th     2.2667     2.2667  and again to 24x
2.2582     2.2582     2.2582 ...
```

with every column.

I've tried to create a vector with these values and then transform with vec2mat and ok I have 121x1488 matrix but repeated by rows:

```
2.2668   2.2668   2.2668  2.2668  2.2668  2.2668 ...    2.2582   2.2582  2.2582  2.2582 ...
```

How to do it by columns?

Comment: Could You paste the code with vec2mat transformation?

Comment: GPT2=repmat(ZHD_GPT2(:),1,24);
X=vec2mat(GPT2,1488);

Answer (score 23):

Suppose you have this *simplified* input and you want to expand columns sequentially `n` times:

```
A   = [1 4
       2 5
       3 6];

szA = size(A); 
n = 3;
```

There are few ways to do that:

- Replicate, then reshape:

  ```
  reshape(repmat(A,n,1),szA(1),n*szA(2))
  ```
- Kronecker product:

  ```
  kron(A,ones(1,n))
  ```
- Using [FEX: `expand()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24536-expand):

  ```
  expand(A,[1 n])
  ```
- Since R2015a, [`repelem()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

  ```
  repelem(A,1,n)
  ```

All yield the same result:

```
ans =
     1     1     1     4     4     4
     2     2     2     5     5     5
     3     3     3     6     6     6
```

Comment: +1 for `kron` solution

Comment: Thanks for three solutions. Is there any preference regarding performance? Actually, I do this in a huge loop which makes the performance quite important.

Comment: @AlirezaMirian Replicate, reshape should be the fastest.

Comment: Agree. kron is a quite an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness. If you want to duplicate along the rows, you can also use rectpulse().

```
A = [1,2,3;...
     4,5,6];

n = 3;

rectpulse(A, n);
```

gives you

```
1  2  3
1  2  3
1  2  3
4  5  6
4  5  6
4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
function [result] = repcolumn(A, n)
    %n - how many times each column from A should be repeated

    [rows columns] = size(A);
    result = repmat(A(:,1),1,n);

    for i = 2:columns
        result = [result,repmat(A(:,i),1,n)];
    end
end
```

There must be an easier way but it does the job.

Comment: Thank You. It is clean enough and it works