# Manually upsample/replicate matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I'm trying to upsample a matrix by two by replicating another matrix, but i'm confused with the code, basically what i want is if:

```
Y = [1,2]
```

then the upsampled version would look like:

```
Up = [1,1,2,2;1,1,2,2]
```

What i've written so far is:

```
[row,col] = size(y)

Up = zeros(row*2,col*2);

for i = 1:2:row*2

     for j = 1:2:col*2

        Up(i, j) = Y(i,j);
        Up(i+1, j) = Y(i,j);
        Up(i, j+1) = Y(i,j);
        Up(i+1, j+1) = Y(i,j);

    end
end
```

but it says Index exceeds matrix dimensions, which i understand is because of the +1s but i'm not sure how else to go about doing this...

Comment: Does this work? `repmat(sort(repmat([1,2], 1, 2)), 2, 1)`

Comment: Are you doing this as a programming exercise, or do you just need to get the matrix resized? Because you could do this in one line with `kron` or `imresize`...

Comment: This question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266804/matlab-repeat-every-column-sequentially-n-times

Comment: @Alex that first solution doesn't work because my data isn't in ascending order, that was just an example, but i'm looking through the second link right now

Comment: okay so my issue is that i need to replicated both column wise and row wise and i'm having trouble doing that at the same time without loops

Comment: Actually nevermind, removing the "sort" fixes the issue thank you!

Comment: removing the sort does not produce the desired output you have written in the question.

Comment: @AprilCrumb Try `kron(Y, ones(2))`. That should duplicate each element twice horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @Alex it does if you do it element by element, instead of replicating the whole matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
Y = [1,2]; % matrix
n = 2; % repetition factor
```

Solution using the [**`repelem` function**](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (introduced in R2015a):

```
Up = repelem(Y,n,n);
```

Solution using **indexing**;

```
Up = Y(ceil(1/n:1/n:end), ceil(1/n:1/n:end));
```

Solution using a **Kronecker product**:

```
Up = kron(Y, ones(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution i ended up using is:

```
[row,col] = size(Y);
Up = zeros(row*2,col*2);
idx_row = 1;

for i = 1:D:row
    idx_col = 1;
    for j = 1:D:col

        Up(i:i+1, j:j+1) = repmat(repmat(Y(idx_row,idx_col),1,2),2,1);
       idx_col = idx_col + 1;
    end
     idx_row = idx_row + 1;
end
```